# quartz job isn't running but quartz tables getting updated

Tags: java, oracle11g, quartz-scheduler, netbeans-7

I'm unable to find what's actual reason but my quartz table are getting updated for `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` and `PREV_FIRE_TIME` but jobs are not running.

**quartz.properties**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName="MyScheduler"
org.quartz.threadPool.class="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount="4"
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread="true"
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer="true"
org.quartz.jobStore.class="org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX"
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass="org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate"
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource="tasksDataStore"
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix="QRTZ_"
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold="60000"
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered="false"
org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl"
org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.user="scott"
org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.password="tiger"
org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.maxConnections="20"
```

Code written for scheduler

```
         JobDetail job = null;
        CronTrigger trigger = null;
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronTrigger.class);

        System.out.println("------- Initializing -------------------");

        // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("/conf/quartz.properties");
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();


        try {
            System.out.println("------- Scheduling Jobs ----------------");
            job = newJob(SchedulerJob.class).withIdentity("job2", "group2").build();

            trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?"))
                    .build();

            Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            // System.out.println(sched.getSchedulerName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("------- Job Already Exist ----------------");
        }
       sched.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start the scheduler using scheduler.start();

Otherwise quartz will persist job data but won't respond to fired triggers and won't actually run anything (stand by mode).

Comment: I'm using `scheduler.start()`. But, when I'm checking running job there I'm getting scheduler status as `STANDBY`

Comment: Can you post the scheduler init code and your quartz.properties ?

Comment: Could you also add the code of how you create your scheduler ?

Comment: Did you try adding some logs to SchedulerJob execute method ?

Comment: Simply I'm printing Current Date and Time using java code

Comment: Maybe because you added the job when the scheduler hasn't started yet is the cause. Try adding .requestRecovery(true) to the JobBuilder, and also maybe try starting the scheduler before adding new jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not to answer in a comment, problem of reputation. Can you develop your problem ? This problem could comes from many factors :

- The job could failed while executing
- The trigger can be vetoed by a trigger listener
- The job can be stoped and report its execution

A simple way to check that is to use a trigger listener and a job listener and log or debug the firing in Quartz.

Comment: I'm using scheduler.start(). But, when I'm checking running job there I'm getting scheduler status as `STANDBY`